# Are there other ways to specify or enter a Unicode code point in C other than using string literals?

Tags: c, string, unicode, ncurses, widestring

In the following program I am trying to provide a Unicode code point to the ncurses function setcchar() as an array string instead of as a string literal. However the output that I'm getting is the first character of the array only, namely the backslash character.

Is there another way to specify a Unicode code point other than as a string literal? And why are the two expressions L"\u4e09" and wcsarr not producing the same result in this context...

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  cchar_t kanji;
  wchar_t wcsarr[7];

  wcsarr[0] = L'\\';
  wcsarr[1] = L'u';
  wcsarr[2] = L'4';
  wcsarr[3] = L'e';
  wcsarr[4] = L'0';
  wcsarr[5] = L'9';
  wcsarr[6] = L'\0';

  initscr();

  setcchar(&kanji, wcsarr, WA_NORMAL, 5, NULL);
  addstr("Code point entered as an array string: ");
  add_wch(&kanji);
  addstr("\n");

  setcchar(&kanji, L"\u4e09", WA_NORMAL, 5, NULL);
  addstr("Code point entered as a string literal: ");
  add_wch(&kanji);
  addstr("\n");
  
  refresh();
  getch();
  endwin();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: They're not producing the same result because they're two different strings? One with six codepoints, one with a single CP.

Comment: And wether wide characters use Unicode or not is system dependant, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array containing the six characters `\u4e09`  is an array containing six characters, just as an array containing a backslash followed by an `n` is an array of two characters, not a newline. The *compiler* converts escape sequence in literals. Nothing (except what you yourself write) does anything to character arrays.

So your array `wcsarr` is not a single wide character. It's a (null-terminated) wide string using six wchar_t values to encode six ascii characters. `setcchar` requires that its second argument contain only one spacing character (possibly followed by several non-spacing combining characters), and your program does not conform to this specification.

You could do something like this:

```
wchar_t wcsarr[] = {0, 0};
wcsarr[0] = L'\u4e09`;
```

If you knew that your locale used Unicode code points as wide character codes, you could write:

```
wcsarr[0] = 0x4e09;
```

since `wchar_t`, like `char`, is an integer type. That's occasionally useful if you need to compute a character code (such as non-latin digits), but normally it's considered better style to use wide character literals.

If you really need to decode a character string containing an escape sequence, you'll need to verify that the syntax is correct and then use something like `strtol` with the base parameter set to 16. Note, however, that `strtol` does not have any mechanism to restrict its argument to exactly four digits, so if the escape sequence appears in text where it might be followed by what looks like a hexadecimal digit, you will have to somehow extract it. Either copy it to a temporary buffer, or null-terminate it if the character string can be modified. Or you could write your own hexadecimal decoder; it's not hard.